# Обладатель кубка или Кубка (Гагарина, Стэнли, России)?

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная, названия

Помогите разобраться, как правильно:
*обладатель **кубка*** (России т. п.) или *обладатель **Кубка***?
Имеется в виду, что Кубок — это турнир, а кубок — это награда за победу в этом турнире.

И второе. Как правильно: сыграть матч с "Торпедо" или сыграть против "Торпедо"?

Answer (score 2):

Вопрос № 279733
Здравствуйте! **Подскажите, пожалуйста, как пишется "обладатель кубка Стэнли" или "обладатель Кубка Стэнли"?** По правилу написания слова "кубок" должно бы писаться в данном случае со строчной буквы, но во всем Интернете нет такого написания ― везде идет все с большой буквы.

Ответ справочной службы русского языка
Правильно: Кубок Стэнли. См.: Лопатин В. В., Нечаева И. В., Чельцова Л. К. Прописная или строчная? Орфографический словарь. М., 2011.

http://www.gramota.tv/spravka/buro/search-answer?s=%D0%9A%D0%A3%D0%91%D0%9E%D0%9A

Получается, что ответа нет.

Как же писать: **обладатель кубка России или обладатель Кубка России?**

Действительно, прописная буква встречается часто, но не всегда.Скорее всего, мы должны писать **победитель Кубка России** (соревнования) и **обладатель кубка России** (спортивной награды).

**КУБОК**  2. Сосуд, ваза (обычно из ценного материала), вручаемые как приз победителям в спортивных состязаниях; само такое состязание.

Ответы Грамоты.ру

1) Слово кубок в значении 'награда' пишется строчными: команда выиграла кубок.

2) Слово Кубок пишется с большой буквы **как первое слово в названии спортивных соревнований**: Кубок Европы по водному поло, Кубок мира, Кубок России. Но: Межконтинентальный кубок.

**О матче**

1) Играть можно с кем-то или против кого-то.

«Спартак» **играл против** московского «Динамо». [Марк Зайчик. В нашем регионе // «Звезда», 2002].  Вчера «Спартак» **играл с** «Динамо».  // «Русская жизнь», 2012]

2) **Вызывает сомнение правильность выражения** **сыграть матч.**  Из словаря: Матч ― это состязание, можно **провести матч**.  Управление: матч кого с кем / между кем-чем. Матч между "Спартаком"и "Динамо".

Answer (score 0):

По ссылке  Jasmin:

**Вопрос** № 273022
Как пишет слово кубок - с прописной или строчной?

**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка:
Кубок пишется с прописной как первое слово названий спортивных наград, соревнований: Кубок Дэвиса, Кубок России по футболу. Ср.: Межконтитентальный кубок (не первое слово названия), пить победное шампанское из кубка (здесь кубок в знач. 'сосуд').

**Вопрос** № 271951
Здравствуйте! Верно ли написаны названия кубка и спортивных состязаний (интересует употребление большой буквы) во фразе: "Он шесть лет подряд выигрывал Кубок наций Гонки чемпионов"?

**Ответ** справочной службы русского языка:
Такое написание корректно.
Дело в том, что спортивный кубок как награда большого спорта обычно является переходящим «трофеем», то есть находится у команды-победителя до игр следующего сезона, в которых определяется новый лидер и - соответственно - обладатель кубка. Наградные спортивные кубки являются главным призом многочисленных соревнований с аналогичным названием и зачастую являются единичными, в одном экземпляре, поэтому пишутся с большой буквы.

Вот, например, Кубок Лорда Стэнли - один из самых старейших и известных спортивных «трофеев» в мире, с богатой и скандальной историей. Этот хоккейный приз, который каждый год вручается победителю плей-офф Национальной хоккейной лиги (НХЛ), был учрежден в 1892 году в Шеффилде (Англия) и имел первоначальное название «Хоккейный Кубок Вызова». Тогда, в конце 19 века, этот спортивный кубок вручался лучшей любительской команде Канады и представлял собой серебряную чашу 18,5 см высотой и 29 см в диаметре.

Сегодня Кубок Стэнли существенно увеличился в размерах - массивная ваза из серебра с цилиндрическим основанием имеет высоту 89,54 см и весит 15,5 кг. Это первый спортивный кубок на планете (второй - Кубок Гагарина), который каждый из обладателей в течение суток может использовать по собственному усмотрению, и единственный трофей в профессиональном спорте, на котором гравируются имена всех игроков, тренеров, менеджеров и персонала команды-чемпиона.

Другого такого кубка нет, а если это приз каких-то соревнований любительских команд или профессиональных, но ниже рангом, там кубки не переходящие, они вручаются победителю навсегда - с указанием года победы, как грамоты,  вот в их названиях слово кубок пишется со строчной буквы, там название кубка будет начинаться с названия соревнования, потому что это символ победы в этом соревновании.

Обладатель Кубка Стэнли - обладатель именно той драгоценной чаши в единственном числе, а не просто обладатель символа победы в Кубке Стэнли, то же касается и  Кубка России, и др. драгоценных "трофеев".

```
сыграть матч с "Торпедо" или против "Торпедо"?
```

Это плеоназм. Матч - игра, получается сыграть игру. Корректно: участвовать в матче с командой "Торпедо" или сыграть против "Торпедо".